# I cannot redirect to another page when i click on the button?

Tags: magento-1.8, forms

After filling the form when i click on the generate button it has to redirect the new page but it is showing the same page after clicking on the button.

```
<div class="button">
    <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
    <button type="Submit" class="button" onclick="document.location.href='http://www.labwise.in/devel/vaccination-details';" title="<?php echo $this->__('Generate') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Generate') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: please explain what your question?

Comment: When i click on generate button it is staying on same page it is not redirecting to the given link

Comment: try the code in answer..

Comment: site not open..

Answer (score 25):

Your button contains  `onclick="document.location.href='http://www.labwise.in/devel/vaccination-details';"`.
This means that when clicking on it, you will get redirected to `http://www.labwise.in/devel/vaccination-details`.
If you want to submit the form at a specific page you have to wrap your form and button in a `<form>` tag.

```
<form action="your url here">
...
</form>
```

and remove the `onclick` from your submit button.

Comment: ThanQ,It has worked but i had a one question can you please help me.How can I add a table to this page with the fields s.no,decription and date

Comment: How to print these details on new page can u please help me

Comment: I don't really understand your new question. But please respect the format of this website. Don't mix questions. If this answer helped you, please accept the answer and ask a new question describing your new problem in as much details as possible.

Comment: How to print these details on my page redirected page.Please suggest me

Answer (score 1):

Starting of with the buttons. There is no technical difference between the buttons. It's only a styling matter. If you use the Magento button (and it's best to do so) you'll get a nicely styled button. Beyond that, both buttons do the same. The submit the form they're attached to.
How ever, make sure the type of the button is submit and not button.
Second, the redirect. The redirect should be done in the controller and not in an onclick event of the button. The flow is roughly something like this.

user fills out form and clicks **button > controller** handles the post data and saves it > controller redirects to desired end page.

Your controller would look something like this

```
  class [Namespace]_[Module]_IndexController
  {

    public function indexAction()
      {
      [...]
      // page that displays your form
       [...]
        }

      public function postoneAction()
       {
       [...]
        // code that handles the post data
        [...]
  // redirect back to the index page, or any other page of your     controller
       $this->_redirect('*/*/index'); 
       }

     public function posttwoAction()
    {
    [...]
     // code that handles the post data differently
     [...]
    // redirect back to the index page, or any other page of your Controller
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
     }
 }
```

Comment: It is not working can u please suggest other way

Comment: it's best way to the redirct

Answer (score 0):

you can use on click

```
 <button onclick="location.href = '<?php  echo $block->abcd(); ?>'" class="scan-order-btn">Warehouse Task Completion Dashboard</button>
```

or direct hardcode link

```
 <button onclick="location.href = 'www.abcd.com'" class="scan-order-btn">Warehouse Task Completion Dashboard</button>
```